# How can I set a github proxy for electron-builder configuration?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder

I'm working under secured closed network and my electron builder dependencies dependencies can't update/donwnload their dependencies so I need to work behind a proxy to github in order to download them,
BUT I don't know where to set it,

```
    13:30:09][Step 12/15] > electron-builder --win --x64
[13:30:09][Step 12/15] 
[13:30:10][Step 12/15]   â€¢ electron-builder version=20.8.1
[13:30:10][Step 12/15]   â€¢ artifacts will be published if draft release exists reason=CI detected
[13:30:11][Step 12/15]   â€¢ loaded configuration file=D:\BuildAgent\work\4247f9413726d058\electron-builder.json
[13:30:11][Step 12/15]   â€¢ description is missed in the package.json appPackageFile=D:\BuildAgent\work\4247f9413726d058\package.json
[13:30:11][Step 12/15]   â€¢ author is missed in the package.json appPackageFile=D:\BuildAgent\work\4247f9413726d058\package.json
[13:30:20][Step 12/15]   â€¢ no native production dependencies
[13:30:21][Step 12/15]   â€¢ packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=1.8.4 appOutDir=app-builds\win-unpacked
[13:30:55][Step 12/15]   â€¢ downloading               path=D:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\electron-builder-cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.0.0 url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.0.0/winCodeSign-2.0.0.7z
[13:30:55][Step 12/15]   â¨¯ Get https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.0.0/winCodeSign-2.0.0.7z: proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that your build runs behind proxy, so please try using http instead of https in your proxy address:

export HTTPS_PROXY="**http**://myproxy.com:8080"

instead of

export HTTPS_PROXY="**https**://myproxy.com:8080"

From here:

https://github.com/jspm/github/issues/59

Comment: Thanks Boris! appriciate